# How can I get the current window's title with char * format in C++ on Windows?

Tags: c++, windows, winapi

I want the write the current window title in console and/or file, and I have trouble with `LPWSTR` to `char *` or `const char *`. My code is:

```
LPWSTR title = new WCHAR();
HWND handle = GetForegroundWindow();
GetWindowText(handle, title, GetWindowTextLength( handle )+1);

/*Problem is here */
char * CSTitle ???<??? title

std::cout << CSTitle;

FILE *file;
file=fopen("file.txt","a+");
fputs(CSTitle,file);
fclose(file);
```

Comment: One `WCHAR` is definitely not enough. Anyway, if you need narrow strings, why not just use `GetWindowTextA`?

Comment: i need unicode window names, is LPSTR and GetWindowTextA return unicode window names?

Comment: Well, trying to convert each character to a 1-byte value isn't going to work, either. Is there any reason you can't just print the wide characters or write them to the file? That would be my suggested route. I also you suggest you use something like `std::wstring` (C++11) or `std::vector<WCHAR>` instead of a plain manually-managed array.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to allocate enough memory for storing title:

```
HWND handle = GetForegroundWindow();
int bufsize = GetWindowTextLength(handle) + 1;
LPWSTR title = new WCHAR[bufsize];
GetWindowText(handle, title, bufsize);
```

Comment: It's still one character long, but instead of having a value of 0, it now starts with a value of `bufsize`.

Comment: @chris, it was my fault, I copied his code and forgot to modify the `new` operation.

Answer (score 4):

You are only allocating enough memory for one character, not the entire string. When `GetWindowText` is called it copies more characters than there is memory for causing undefined behavior. You can use `std::string` to make sure there is enough memory available and avoid managing memory yourself.

```
#include <string>

HWND handle = GetForegroundWindow();
int bufsize = GetWindowTextLength(handle);
std::basic_string<TCHAR>  title(bufsize, 0);
GetWindowText(handle, &title[0], bufsize + 1);
```

Comment: @JonathanLeffler No. basic_string handles the null terminator. We're only interested in the character count.

Comment: @CaptainObvlious: using `title(bufsize, 0)` gets all except the last character of the window title, using `title(bufsize + 1, 0)` makes room for the last character

Comment: sorry, meant to say `GetWindowText(handle, &title[0], bufsize + 1)` instead of `GetWindowText(handle, &title[0], bufsize)`